# Laravel: Check input field is empty or not submitted

Tags: php, laravel, input

I have multiple forms on different sites. They all end in the same route.
The user has the ability to set some types of a model on null.
Not every form submits all fields of the model. So for example:

Model has this fields: `Name, Adress, Phone, Text`

Form 1 submits `Name, Adress, Phone`

Form 2 submits `Adress, Text`

If I submit form 1, my model would look like this:

```
$model->name = Name;
$model->adress = Adress;
$model->phone = Phone;
$model->text = null;
```

But I dont want to overwrite Text. I want Text to be the value it was before the submit. But if I submit form 2, I want to change text or even set it to null.

However, how can I check if a form name was in the submitted form (even if it is actually `null`)?

Curently, this is my update Routine in my controller:

```
...
$this->artSkill = ($request->artSkill) ? $request->artSkill : null;
$this->craftsmanSkill = ($request->craftsmanSkill) ? $request->craftsmanSkill : null;
$this->ownInitiativeSkill = ($request->ownInitiativeSkill) ? $request->ownInitiativeSkill : null;
...
```

Comment: It looks like you need to take advantage of Laravel's `request validation`

Comment: But how? I can't take the input field as requiered because it actually can be null or even not submitted, if the form doesn't wan't to change the field. And my wish is to call the route from ajax to only update one field.

Comment: you can add a hidden input field shows if this form1 or 2 was submitted , then you can decide

Comment: @mooga but thats not really OOP and I would love to have it usable for every possible use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the model's `update()` method and only pass in the values that are not null:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#updates

E.g.

```
$input = $request->all();
$input = array_filter($input);
$model->update($input);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can opt for the following logic:

```
$model->text = $request->filled('text') ? $request->get('text', $model->text) : null;
```

If `text` is not present in the request, its value is null.

If `text` is present and its value is blank, it is kept the original value.

Comment: I‘ll test it today. If it works, that is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: According to the Laravel documentation filled will return false if the input is null. But the has method will „return true even if the input value is an empty string or null“

Comment: It is best if you focus on the ternary operator example and fit it to your current need.